# How to open a window on click on NSStatusItem?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, menu, window, nsstatusitem

I'm pretty new to cocoa, so please excuse me for any stupid mistakes I make.
I have a NSStatusItem, which I want to use to open up a menu. However as far as I know and have heard across different forms, without a custom view you are restricted to just a pop down menu. Is this true? And if so how do you make a custom view to do something (e.g. open a window in my case)? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, it is not true. You need to set up the target and action for the status item to call a method which does what you want (opens the window).

```
// This goes where you set up the status item
NSStatusItem *statusItem; // You need to get this from the status bar
[statusItem setTarget:self];
[statusItem setAction:@selector(openWindow:)];

// This method is called when the status item is clicked
- (void)openWindow:(id)sender {
    NSWindow *window = [self window]; // Get the window to open
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
}
```

You may also want to call `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:nil];` to your openWindow: method to ensure that the window you open is not behind some other application's window.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I summarized this in a blog post http://www.jademind.com/blog/posts/show-nswindow-below-your-nsstatusitem again